# Programmatically double click on systemtray icons Windows xp/7

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, windows-7, windows-xp

How can I Programmatically double click on a system tray icon in Windows xp/7 and cause an app window to open ?

Comment: You're trying to solve this problem the wrong way. Send the application a message asking it to open. Don't try and double-click on an icon. There's no way you can get that work reliably in both Windows XP *and* 7.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Program you want to open your own App ? Then you can send messages to this process to force it to open.

This article may help you with sending messages between processes.
[send message to other process](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/ccee7ae6-75ca-4916-89cf-a099d12074a7)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Using Spy++ looks that "User Promoted Notification Area" offers no way to click a button and you have no control what icon is visibile.

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx to send an input to the OS and double click on a specific position :

```
void MouseMove (double x, double y ) 
{
    double fx = x*65535.0f;
    double fy = y*65535.0f;
    INPUT  Input={0};
    Input.type      = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.mi.dwFlags  = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE|MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
    Input.mi.dx = (long)fx;
    Input.mi.dy = (long)fy;
    ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
}
void lClick(){
    INPUT Input={0};
    // left down
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
    ::ZeroMemory(&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
    // left up
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.mi.dwFlags  = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    ::SendInput(1,&Input,sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

and then call mousemove on the place where is the icon, and lClick twice.
But this would implicate that the program task bar icon doesn't move... Depends on what the program is, and if you know the computer or not.